# Testing with Jest mock

Tags: javascript, jestjs, flux

I'm using the Flux design pattern in my application and I need to test that an Application Action emits on a given Store in the payload that a component sends.

Using a Dispatcher I send a payload like the following:

```
dispatcher.dispatch({
  action: ACTION_NAME,
  foo: 'bar',
  emitOn: {
   store: SomeStore, // extends EventEmitter
   componentIds: ['Foo-Bar']
  }
}
```

The dispatcher is implemented like so (Not necessarily important)

```
Dispatcher.register((payload) => {
 Actions.call(payload);
 return true;
});
```

When the dispatcher `calls` an action the object `Actions` will call that action and when the action finishes it should call `emit` on the given store.

My question is how do I test this in my application? I want to know if it's possible to check that `emit` was called after an action finishes.

To finish an action this function is called `Actions.finish(payload)`

And if you're curious what `finish` looks like:

```
  finish(payload) {
    payload.emitOn.map(emitter => {
      var store = emitter.store;
      emitter.componentIds.map(id => {
        store.emit(id);
      });
    });
  }
```

My current testing code, but the Error is never thrown:

```
  jest.mock('./TestStore.js', () => {
    return function() {
      return {
        emit: () => {
          throw new Error('Test Error');
        }
      };
    };
  });

  let ACTION = 'Test-Action';
  let payload = {
    action: ACTION,
    emitOn: [{
      store: TestStore, // The store to emit on
      componentIds: ['Test-Id']
    }]
  };

  expect(() => {
    AppActions.finish(payload);
  }).toThrow(Error);
```

Answer (score 0):

SO for anyone caring about how to test if a function is called you can spy on a function using `jest.spyOn`

I found this here [Understanding Jest Mocks](https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c)

I changed my testing code (Much cleaner and the right approach to this kind of testing)

```
  const emitMock = jest.spyOn(TestStore, 'emit');

  let ACTION = 'Test-Action';
  let payload = {
    action: ACTION,
    emitOn: [{
      store: TestStore, // The store to emit on
      componentIds: ['Test-Id']
    }]
  };

  AppActions.finish(payload);

  expect(emitMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```